# Can MSI interrupt route to multiple cpus？

Tags: linux, x86, intel, interrupt, pci-e

> Message signalled interrupts (MSI) is an optional feature that enables PCI devices to request service by writing a system-specified message to a system-specified address (PCI DWORD memory write transaction). The transaction address specifies the message destination while the transaction data specifies the message. System software is expected to initialize the message destination and message during device configuration, allocating one or more non-shared messages to each MSI capable function.

Can MSI interrupt route to multiple cpus?
for example: `echo F > /proc/irq/msi_irq/smp_affinity`

From my opinion:

1. MSI interrupt can route to multiple cpus. when cpu receive interrupt message, use the destination info to route interrupts to multiple cpus.
2. MSI interrupt can not route to multiple cpus. MSI interrupt message can only write to LAPIC, so can only trigger interrupt to one cpu.

But, which opinion is right?

Comment: MSIs can target multiple CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MSIs can be dispatched to multiple logical CPUs.

Chapter 10.11 (Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller / Message Signalled Interrupts) of the Intel SDM vol 3 describes the format of the address destination of an MSI:

[image: Format of the address destination of an MSI]

The `RH` (Redirection Hint) and `DM` (Destination mode) fields change the meaning of the `Destination ID` field:

> • When RH is 0, the interrupt is directed to the processor listed in the Destination ID field.
> • When RH is 1 and the physical destination mode is used, the Destination ID field must not be set to FFH;
> it must point to a processor that is present and enabled to receive the interrupt.
> • When RH is 1 and the logical destination mode is active in a system using a flat addressing model, the Destination ID field must be set so that **bits set to 1 identify processors that are present and enabled to
> receive the interrupt.**
> • If RH is set to 1 and the logical destination mode is active in a system using cluster addressing model,
> then Destination ID field must not be set to FFH; **the processors identified with this field must be
> present and enabled to receive the interrupt**.

---

If by `msi_irq` in `/proc/irq/msi_irq/smp_affinity` you mean an IRQ number that uses MSI then yes, setting that pseudo-file to `f` will limit said IRQ to the four logical CPUs selected.
In fact, as far as interrupt dispatching goes, only interrupts using the legacy PIC cannot have an affinity. IO-APIC interrupts and MSI can always target a group of processors.

Comment: I have test "echo F > /proc/irq/msi_irq/smp_affinity" on Linux, found that msi interrupt only dispatched to only one cpu. and '/proc/irq/msi_irq/effective_affinity' indicates the cpu to which the msi interrupt can dispatched.

Comment: MSIs can be dispatched to multiple CPUs and have an affinity. I can't tell why your kernel doesn't respect your decision. Maybe you have something else at play that override your request?